# Corda's Ledger Sync not syncing vault states in certain circumstances

Tags: corda

We are currently working on integrating the Ledger Sync Service in our Cordapp: https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/ledger-sync

During our own tests, we experienced that in certain circumstances the ledger is not successfully synchronized/repaired after a crash.

Our test does the following:

- Node `A` and `B` transact with each other, creating a State `S`.
- Node `B` crashes and recovers to a state, where it does not know `S`.
- Node `A` creates a new transaction, that consumes state `S`
- Node `B` uses the ledger sync service to recover all states.

In the background, the following happens: When node `A` creates the Tx that consumes the state `S`, node `B` will also receive the old Tx that created state `S` as dependency. From that point, the Tx is recorded in the database of node `B` and can be retrieved by calling `serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(txId)`.

However, querying the vault for `CONSUMED` or `ALL` states will not return the old state `S`. Running the ledger sync will report that the node is out of sync, saying that the transaction that created state `S` is missing.

Calling the repair will not successfully repair and consecutive runs of `RequestLedgersSyncFlow` will keep reporting missing transactions.

I am not sure that this use case is actually supported (creating Txs while the ledger is out of sync) but I think if it is not a supported use case, it is hard to make sure that nodes are not transacting with each other when one of the nodes is out of sync.

I hope the issue is clear, otherwise I can also prepare and provide a test for it.

**Update:**
Upon request, here I created a fork of the Corda Solutions repo and added a test that showcases the error: https://github.com/marioschlipf/corda-solutions/commit/fe1ab5917c971fcf9732bf8af7d0f2c1800b5e37

Comment: Please add a test if possible, could you also provide the snippet you use to query ALL states.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you simulate the _crash_ of a node? https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/blob/1501624421ec23f5d8adc8137303c218ff3ab905/bn-apps/ledger-sync/ledger-sync-service/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/businessnetworks/ledgersync/TransactionRecoveryFlow.kt#L33 will skip over any transactions that are still available to the node (be it in a cached state or in the vault).

Comment: @Adrian I added a test, see my original question

Comment: @mritz_p We are backing up the h2 database and restoring it with the node shut down. I think this is a more robust test than fiddling around with SQL. However, I managed to showcase the bug with the test setup that R3 uses in their setup. See my original question. Edit: I have seen the line of code you mentioned, removing this filter does not change anything, tested this already.

Comment: @mario.schlipf shouldn't the assertion in l. 186 be `assertEquals(0, ledgerSyncResult2[node1.fromNetwork().identity()]!!.missingAtRequester.size)`. Because you ran recovery before?

Comment: @mritz_p You are right, the assertion asserts on the bug and it succeeds. Should be changed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you change the condition I pointed to earlier (https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/blob/1501624421ec23f5d8adc8137303c218ff3ab905/bn-apps/ledger-sync/ledger-sync-service/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/businessnetworks/ledgersync/TransactionRecoveryFlow.kt#L33) to not filter any states (i.e. make the lambda return `true`) this test will pass with the correct assertion (`0`). This seems to be related to caching. It would be interesting to see what you observe on a deployed node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186918/discussion-between-mritz-p-and-mario-schlipf).

Answer (score 2):

I have recreated the scenario with four nodes running *Ledger Sync Service* built from master (most recent commit `839dfb8772c3b08447183a84e336a527a0f3975b`). I have modified `BogusFlow` in the following way to allow for consumption of the input state:

```
/**
 * A trivial flow that is merely used to illustrate synchronisation by persisting meaningless transactions in
 * participant's vaults
 */
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class BogusFlow(
        private val them: Party,
        private val precursor: UniqueIdentifier? = null
) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()

        val cmd = Command(BogusContract.Commands.Bogus(), listOf(them.owningKey))

        val builder = TransactionBuilder(notary)

        precursor?.let {
            val result = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(BogusState::class.java, LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(it)))
            val inputState = result.states.single()
            builder.addInputState(inputState)
        }

        builder.addOutputState(BogusState(ourIdentity, them), BOGUS_CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(cmd).apply {
                    verify(serviceHub)
                }

        val partiallySigned = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(builder)

        val session = initiateFlow(them)

        val fullySigned = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partiallySigned, setOf(session)))

        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySigned))
    }
}
```

The CorDapp containing this flow is deployed to three nodes (Alice `A`, Bob `B`, Charlie `C`). A non-validating Notary (`N`) is used.

Consider the following steps to simulate failure and restore.

1. Start `A`, `B`, `C` and `N` using H2 as database
2. As `A`, invoke `net.corda.businessnetworks.ledgersync.BogusFlow`, targeting `O=Bob Ltd., L=London, C=GB`
3. Shut down node `A` and destroy the database i.e. `rm persistence.mv.db`
4. As `B`, run a vaultQuery for contractStateType `net.corda.businessnetworks.ledgersync.BogusState` to validate `B` has knowledge of the unconsumed state following *2*. The output should contain a `linearId`. Take note of this ID.
5. As `B`, start a flow with `C`, utilising the `linearId` obtained in *4* as precursor. I.e. `flow start net.corda.businessnetworks.ledgersync.BogusFlow them: "O=Charlie SARL, L=Paris, C=FR", precursor: "2429c289-0ccb-4adb-9714-32ee3d0d7f12"`. Note that in a production use case your contract code might prohibit this transaction from being executed in the first place, given `A` has not signed it.
6. As `B`, run `vaultQuery contractStateType: net.corda.businessnetworks.ledgersync.BogusState` and validate that there is an unconsumed state with participants `B` and `C` (i.e. `"participants" : [ "O=Bob Ltd., L=London, C=GB", "O=Charlie SARL, L=Paris, C=FR" ]`).
7. As `A`, bring the node back up, creating a new H2 database.
8. As `A`, start `EvaluateLedgerConsistencyFlow` (i.e. `connection.proxy.startFlow(::EvaluateLedgerConsistencyFlow, listOf(alice, bob, charlie))`). This should return `{O=Bob Ltd., L=London, C=GB=false, O=Charlie SARL, L=Paris, C=FR=true}` indicating `A` is out of sync with `B`.
9. As `A`, run `RequestLedgersSyncFlow` (i.e. `connection.proxy.startFlow(::RequestLedgersSyncFlow, listOf(alice, bob, charlie))`). This will return a summary of missing transactions (e.g. `{O=Bob Ltd., L=London, C=GB=LedgerSyncFindings(missingAtRequester=[BAA58E9E9E2025181F00459FCE8B0D035705A38D1068A0F4C4BAB53F3F56FB40], missingAtRequestee=[]), O=Charlie SARL, L=Paris, C=FR=LedgerSyncFindings(missingAtRequester=[], missingAtRequestee=[])}`).
10. As `A`, run `TransactionRecoveryFlow`, **passing in the result of 9**. E.g. `connection.proxy.startFlow(::TransactionRecoveryFlow, report)` where `report` is the result of the previous step.
11. As `A`, to validate re-run `EvaluateLedgerConsistencyFlow` which will return the result `{O=Bob Ltd., L=London, C=GB=true, O=Charlie SARL, L=Paris, C=FR=true}`, indicating the discrepancy was resolved.
12. To validate furthermore, as `A`, run a vault query (i.e. `VaultQueryCriteria(status = ALL), PageSpecification(), Sort(emptyList()), BogusState::class.java`) to retrieve the contents and verify that the state has been recreated.

Does this cover the scenario you are describing?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this issue! The scenario you describe is a little different. In our scenario, the second transaction is also between node `A` and `B`, which causes A to retrieve the issuing transaction when it signs the consuming transaction. Regarding your point 5: You are right that in a production use case, node `A` *might* need to sign the second tx. However, in our use case, this is not necessary and `B` is allowed to consume without `A` signing the transaction. Have you tested deploying the exact contract I posted?